# Typeahead.js: Force reload of local dataset

Tags: javascript, typeahead, typeahead.js

I want to implement a raw fallback option akin to Twitter's web app where it has a final autocomplete option of the value of the input (e.g. `Search all people for {{input.val()}}`):

[image: Fallback "Search all people for {{input.val()}}]

My current implementation fails because [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) doesn't reload local datasets thus the desired effect only happens on the first keyup event:

```
var plusone = [
    {
        value: '',
        tokens: ''
    }
];

$('#name').keyup(function () {
    plusone[0].value = $('#name').val();
    plusone[0].tokens = $('#name').val();
});

$('#name').typeahead(
    [
        {
            local: plusone
        }
    ]
);
```

According to the documentation and this [tutorial](http://tosbourn.com/2013/07/javascript/refreshing-local-data-with-typeahead-js/) there is no way of reinitialising typeahead without destroying it first which I'd prefer not to have to do for performance. Any suggestions on a better implementation or a fix would be much appreciated (if anyone from Twitter is out there I'd love to know your implementation).

Comment: There's not a great way of achieving that functionality in v0.9.x, but  I'm hoping you'll be able to do it in v0.10. Once I release v0.10, I'll circle back here and give a proper answer.

Comment: @jharding Okay thanks for the update, I look forward to having a robust solution.

Comment: Brodie, did you ever find a solution.  I am faced with the same situation and wondered what you came up with.

Comment: @DavidRobbins v0.10 of Typeahead is out now - I haven't had time to look into it but it sounds like the above is easily achievable now. Will post back when I know.

Comment: @Brodie - thx.  I ended up going the re-initialization route, and performance wasn't too bad.  In my case the local data item is really small - 15 items max.  It works in conjunction with Knockoutjs.

Comment: @jharding you should circle back for a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a new dataset to typeahead with a custom source function.

```js
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: 'nba.json'
});

nbaTeams.initialize();

$('#autosuggest-input').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    hint: false
}, {
    name: 'nba-teams',
    displayKey: 'team',
    source: nbaTeams.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
    }
}, {
    name: 'advanced-search',
    displayKey: 'name',
    // For every dataset, typeahead expects you to provide a source property
    // which is a function that accepts two arguments: query and cb. And you
    // can do whatever you want in that function. In this case, what we do
    // is that regardless of the query provided, you will always return the
    // same result.
    source: function(query, cb) {
        var result = [{
            'name': 'Advance search for "' + query + '"'
        }];
        cb(result);
    },
    templates: {
        header: '<div style="border-top: 1px solid black;"></div>'
    }
});
```

Demo & credits: http://plnkr.co/edit/cjL6nZtShyxmLjWxzdBC?p=preview

Comment: This is indeed now possible since v0.10 shipped, thank you for the example.